# ssh_exchange_identification error using git

Tags: git, github, ssh, gitlab

After some time of not using git, suddenly I'm not able to make any actions with any remote (`pull`/`push` etc..). Tried Gitlab repositories also but got the same results, so I suppose something changed in my computer. Any ideas of what this could be?

```
Kostass-MacBook-Air:slot tsal$ ssh -vvv  git@github.com
OpenSSH_7.6p1, LibreSSL 2.6.2
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 48: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to github.com port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/tsal/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/tsal/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/tsal/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/tsal/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/tsal/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/tsal/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/tsal/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/tsal/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6
debug1: ssh_exchange_identification: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
```

Comment: Try with : sudo vi +48 /etc/ssh/ssh_config

put a # at the start of this line.

Comment: @GovindParashar Tried it and I'm just not getting the ````debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 48: Applying options for *```` line but the same results, 400 Bad Request

Comment: might be below link will help https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Logging_and_Troubleshooting#Client_Logging
it seems that the corresponding public key files got deleted.

Comment: "ssh_exchange_identification: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request" You're connecting to an HTTP server, not an SSH server.

Comment: Thank you @Kenster it seems that this is the problem and thank you again for mentioning it. Can I please ask you if you imagine any way of finding where it is being connected if it's not the correct ssh server. Nothing runs on port 22 for example. What else could be?